# what does the output of this code mean? printf("%d", "x");

Tags: c, printf

Here is the full code

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(void) {

    printf("%d", "x");

    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

The output is 15620184. Logically is should return the numeral value of the string "x". But x itself is not a string.

Comment: This code is undefined behavior, don't use it.

Comment: I was just playing around with the language to understand how things work. So the returned value is a garbage value that doesnt mean anything?

Comment: Have you got any warning from compiler??

Comment: It probably is the address of the pointer to `"x"` but since it's undefined behavior ...

Comment: @abhiarora No warnings.

Comment: Always compile with `-Wall -Wextra` to warn you of things you shouldn't be doing.

Comment: Well, lesson learnt from playing around with the language: the printf family of functions is royally stupid and lacks any form of type safety. When you misuse them, you might not get compiler diagnostics or even notice the bugs. And then the undefined behavior bugs may suddenly surface after release. It is a good idea to avoid printf/scanf functions, as well as the whole of stdio.h, in production code.

Comment: I actually question if this is undefined behavior.   As far as I can see, it will properly put out some integer value (somewhere between INT_MIN and INT_MAX), clean up the stack properly, and continue to run just fine.  There is no chance of [nasal demons](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=nasal%20demons).  If you don't have nasal demons, you don't have UB.

Comment: @abelenky By definition, passing any parameter with a type not expected by the corresponding specifier is *undefined behavior*. Read the standard.

Comment: @iharob:  I believe `char*` is freely convertible to `int`, no cast required.  UB only comes about when the parameter is not *convertible* to the format specifier.

Comment: @abelenky not if the `int` size is different from the `char*` size.

Comment: @iharob i am busy studying math, electric, electronic, physics. i dont know when i will have time to read the standart ;( go to university they said... it will be fine they said...

Comment: @abelenky A general conversion from char* to int. is either implementation-defined or undefined. 6.3.2.3 of the standard applies: "Any pointer type may be converted to an integer type. Except as previously specified, the
result is implementation-defined. If the result cannot be represented in the integer type, the behavior is undefined. The result need not be in the range of values of any integer type."

Comment: @abelenky But as a the special case for the printf snowflake family of functions, 7.21.6.1/9 also states that: "If a conversion specification is invalid, the behavior is undefined. If any argument is
not the correct type for the corresponding conversion specification, the behavior is
undefined." So this code could either be undefined in one way or it could be undefined in two different ways.

Comment: @AnılErtürk please do understand that in **C language** playing with the language and seeing what it does is not a proper way to learn - especially without the common compiler warnings and pedantry enabled, due to so much of things being implementation-dependent or altogether undefined. The proper way to learn C is to read the standards and compiler documentation, or even a good reputable book. This applies much less to languages such as Python or Java, which have way stricter language specifications.

Comment: @abelenky (&Lundin) not only does converting `char*` to `int` require a cast, see 6.5.16.1, conversion only occurs where the target type is specified by cast or known: assignment and initialization, function return, and passing to a *prototyped* parameter. Varargs including `*printf` data don't have declared types so the compiler *can't* convert, and instead does only the default *promotions*, see 6.5.2.2p6,7.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala i combine both

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I want to make it clear as other have said that this code is wrong because it has undefined behavior so could do absolutely anything on your platform. Don't do this...  However to aid understanding :-

`"x"` is a string constant and this decays to a pointer to the string and passed as a parameter to `printf`. You've asked it to print an "int" so it interprets the bytes of the address as if they were an `int` and prints those.

In practice this will print the address that the string is stored at as a decimal number.

But nothing in the standard guarantees this, it could do anything, and is likely to differ on other platforms. In general though, due to the way C is implement though in most cases it will do what I've described.

Note than on some 64 bit platforms an int is 32 bits but an address is 64 bits so this is likely to *at best* only print an integer based on half the bytes of the address.

As others have said it's undefined and bad so don't do this, but it's still useful to understand what it's actually doing.

Edit: As suggested... If you want to interpret the data passed properly use `%p` instead of `%d` which tells `printf` to interpret the data passed as a memory address rather than an `int`. Although the format is system dependent it's likely to be print the same `int`, and is properly defined behavior then

Comment: Mention the `%p` format specifier for printing pointer values and the answer would be perfect.

Comment: Added a sentence at the end. Feel free to improve it :P

Answer (score 7):

This code is "**UNDEFINED BEHAVIOR**", you should never use it, to print a string of characters you MUST use `"%s"` as the specifier, to print the address stored in a pointer you MUST use `"%p"` and cast the pointer to `void *`, example

```
printf("%p\n", (void *) "x");
```

ALWAYS add a **trailing** `"\n"` character to `printf()` to *flush* the output buffer, that's only unnecessary with `stderr`, but it's still good to develop the habit.

Also, `"x"` **IS** a string, and if you want the ascii value of `'x'` the character then, this

```
printf("%d\n", 'x');
```

note the single quotes.

Please read [print(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/sprintf.3.html), and learn about the many specifiers handled by `printf()` and family.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. As i said above i was playing around with the language to see what is doing what.

Comment: Not sure if the `(void *)` before `"x"` is required.

Comment: @MichaelWalz Perhaps, but I remember that I read it was mandatory. Although I understand that casting to/from `void *` is not needed in [tag:c].

Comment: @MichaelWalz Nope, it's required. There is no default argument promotion for pointers for variadic function arguments. If it needs a `void*`, you need the cast there.

Comment: @iharob as I mentioned, there's no default promotion happens, so the casting __is__ required.

Comment: @SouravGhosh of course it is required, now I understand, stupid remark. Thanks.

Comment: @MichaelWalz [The standard states that](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.21.6.1p8) "_The conversion specifiers and their meanings are: [...] `p` The argument shall be a pointer to void_". Violating a 'shall' = UB.

Answer (score 4):

> what does this code do? printf(“%d”, “x”);

The code will have undefined behavior. The code you have pasted will give warning. Have a look at the warning that i have got by compiling your code with `gcc`.

```
warning: format ‘%d’ expects argument of type ‘int’, but argument 2 has type ‘char *’ [-Wformat=]
  printf("%d", "x");
```

You can get to know after looking at the above warning that in place of `"x"` you should pass a variable or constant of type `int` but you have passed a pointer to null-terminated character array (`which is "x"`). It is because you have specified a format specifier which is `"%d"` in your printf function which requires a `int` data type variable or constant.

> Logically is should return the numeral value of the string "x"

To print the numerical value of variable of type char or character constant (`'x'`), use printf as

```
printf("%d", 'x'): //Remeber character literal in c are stored as int
```

To print the character array `"x"`, use printf as

```
printf("%s", "x"); //OR
printf("x");
```

To print the address stored in a pointer, you must use "%p" format specifier as

```
printf("%p", "x");
```

There are many format specifiers in c. Few are given below-

```
%c - For Character Variable
%d - For Integers
%f - For Double
%s - For Null-Terminated Character Array
%p - For Pointers (of void * type)
```

Comment: Your table is at best imprecise.  `%f` - `double`, `%d` is for `int`, `%p` `void *`, etc.  `printf("%p", "x");` --> `printf("%p", (void *) "x");`  In C, `'x'` is a _character constant_

Answer (score 2):

Essentially, you're attempting to print the address of the string literal `"x"` as a decimal integer, which isn't guaranteed to work.

The *expression* `"x"` has type "2-element array of `char`"; since the expression is not the operand of the `sizeof` or unary `&` operators, it is converted ("decays") to an expression of type "pointer to `char`", and the value of the expression is the address of the first character of the string.

The `d` conversion specifier expects its corresponding argument to have type `int`; you're passing an argument of type `int *`, so the behavior is undefined.  The output *may* be an accurate representation of the address value as a decimal integer, or it *may* be total garbage.

Types matter, and specific conversion specifers expect their corresponding arguments to be of a specific type (adapted from [Harbison & Steele](http://careferencemanual.com), § 15.11.7):

```
Output Format     Specifier        Argument Type
-------------     ---------        -------------
Decimal Integer     hhi,hhd                 char
 (Signed)             hi,hd                short
                        i,d                  int
                      li,ld                 long
                    lli,lld            long long
                      zi,zd               size_t
                      ti,td            prtdiff_t
                      ji,jd             intmax_t

Decimal Integer         hhu                 char
 (Unsigned)              hu                short
                          u                  int
                         lu                 long
                        llu            long long
                         zu               size_t
                         tu            prtdiff_t
                         ju             intmax_t

Octal Integer           hho         unsigned char
                         ho        unsigned short
                          o          unsigned int
                         lo         unsigned long
                        llo    unsigned long long
                         zo                size_t
                         to             ptrdiff_t
                         jo              intmax_t

Hexadecimal         hhx,hhX         unsigned char
 Integer              hx,hX        unsigned short
                        x,X          unsigned int
                      lx,lX         unsigned long
                    llx,llX    unsigned long long
                      zx,zX                size_t
                      tx,tX             ptrdiff_t
                      jx,jX              intmax_t

Decimal Float          f,lf                double 
                         Lf           long double

Decimal Float,    e,E,le,lE                double
 Exponential          Le,LE           long double     
 Notation           

Decimal Float,    g,G,lg,lG                double
 Same as f or         Lg,LG           long double
 e depending on 
 value

Hexadecimal       a,A,la,lA                double
 Float                La,LA           long double

Single Character          c                   int
Single Wide Character    lc                wint_t

String                    s                char *
Wide String              ls             wchar_t *

Pointer Value             p                void *
```

Note that the representation of a pointer value is implementation-defined.  Most platforms you're likely to work on will output an integral value in hex notation.  Some may output the string "null" for a NULL pointer.  Some may use a completely different representation.

Note that, to print a pointer value, you should explicitly cast the argument to `void *` if it isn't already:

```
printf( "%p\n", (void *) "x" );
```

This is probably the only place in C where you need to explicitly cast a pointer value to `void *`.